# Establish a 95% explained variance while carrying out a pipline process

Tags: python, python-3.x, pipeline, random-forest

I am using a `standard scaler`, `PCA` and `Random Forest` to classify some data.  I wanted to use the `pipeline` methodology, however, I do not know how to let the `pipeline` know that I want the `n_components` = 95% explained variance.  How can I set up the code to calculate this number in the `pipeline` environment.

Here is the code:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

pipe = Pipeline([('scaler', StandardScaler()),
  #  ('pca', PCA(n_components=n_to_reach_95)),
('pca', PCA(n_components=15)),
 ('clf', RandomForestClassifier())])

# Declare a hyperparameter grid
parameter_space = {
    'clf__n_estimators': [10,50,100],
    'clf__criterion': ['gini', 'entropy'],
    'clf__max_depth': np.linspace(10,50,11),
}

clf = GridSearchCV(pipe, parameter_space, cv = 5, scoring = "accuracy", verbose = True) # model


pipe.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

Answer (score 1):

sklearn supports notation like `n_components = 0.95` in fact.